# Media Streaming Server

Tags: server, multimedia, mediaserver

I'm looking for a media stream server (specially audio streams) for installing  on my Ubuntu server box.

Is there any lightweight, easy configurable solution?

It's awesome if this solution is able to install on a high bandwidth server and gets a stream from a low bandwidth server and serves it for many clients. (simply because the original server hasn't enough BW to serve media for many clients)

(My server is a LAMP server, but I'm looking for a good solution for one of my clients to stream his audio for one hour every week)

Comment: Du solltest schon genauer sagen, was du streamen möchtest und wohin... Ein Media-Streaming-Server für das flv-Format ist zum Beispiel der Red5-server: http://www.red5.org/

Comment: @Michael K: Thanks for your response, Let me explain, I have a server with very high BW. I'm using this server as a lamp server. at the other hand, my friend want to broadcast his podcast at a specific time of week, but his BW is too low to serve media for many clients. I decided to help him, but I don't know exactly how! I'm looking for a solution to install that on my server and serve his podcast for clients. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set up VLC as a media streaming server and I think it will cover off what you want to do, have a look at this [Overview of the VideoLAN streaming solution](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html).

It has a link to the [documentation wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo_New) for more info, you can also find many video's online that step you through how to set it up.